# Get Elements behind Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need a help from you. I have two elements "iFrame" and "canvas" in an HTML page. iFrame has loaded external HTML page and the canvas is overlying on it. Canvas helps a user to draw on the page. I have some buttons on the external loaded page which is behind on the canvas and inside iFrame. I couldn't get the events from them. How can I make the buttons work even canvas at the top of the page? Any logic or idea? Please help me.

Comment: you would set CSS of the canvas: `pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.5;`

Comment: Wow. Excellent Dandavis. I was spending more times for it. This is what I expected. Lots of thanks. :)

Comment: `pointer-events` makes it easy! glad to help.